# POCO HTTPS Request Verify Server Certificate

Tags: c++, https, poco, poco-libraries

I am using POCO HTTPSClientSession for executing a HTTPS POST request. I want to compute SHA1 of the server certificate before transmitting any data. How can this be achieved?
This is sample of creating context which doesn't verify server certificate. The basic requirement is to fetch the server certificate during the SSL handshake and do a custom verification of the server certificate.

```
const Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context( new Poco::Net::Context( Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "",Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE ) );
Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(),context);
Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST,uri.getPath(), Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
```

Any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help you. Remove the parameter context from the session constructor. It will force to check the SSL certificate.

```
Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort() );
Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST,uri.getPath(), Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
```